# Linq to entities - How to define left join for grouping?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

We have two tables - Tasks and TasksUsers (users assigned to task). Task has EntityCollection called TaskUsers.

This query returns number of tasks per username:

```
model.TaskCountByAssignee =
            (
            from t in TaskRepository.List()
            from tu in t.TaskUsers
            group tu by tu into tug
                select new {Count = tug.Count(), UserName = tug.Key.Username}).ToList()
```

This query returns:

Administrator 11 
LukLed 5

I want it to return:

Administrator 11 
LukLed 5 
null 10

Some of tasks don't have any assignment, but I still want them in my result set. Normally, in SQL, it is achieved by changing `join` to `left join`. In Linq, outside EF, I could use DefaultIfEmpty(). How can it be done in linq to entities?

Comment: Are you sure you can't use DefaultIfEmpty()?  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin

Comment: @Foole: I wrote, I could use it, if it wasn't EntityFramework, but DefaultIfEmpty doesn't work with EF.

Comment: `DefaultIfEmpty` works in EF4, but not in EF1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first try would be:

```
model.TaskCountByAssignee = (
        (from t in TaskRepository.List()
         from tu in t.TaskUsers
         group tu by tu.UserName into tug
         select new {Count = tug.Count(), UserName = tug.Key})
        .Union(from t in TaskRepository.List()
               where !t.TaskUsers.Any()
               group t by 1 into tug
               select new {Count = tug.Count(), UserName = null}).ToList();
```

Or something along those lines. Or just use two queries. I don't know if this is the best way, though. As I noted in comments, this is *far* easier in EF 4.