# Entity framework left join

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, left-join

How do I change this query so it returns all u.usergroups?

```
from u in usergroups
from p in u.UsergroupPrices
select new UsergroupPricesList
{
UsergroupID = u.UsergroupID,
UsergroupName = u.UsergroupName,
Price = p.Price
};
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/SudheersBlog/archive/2009/06/11/132758.aspx) can help.  it was on another question here on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376701/linq-to-entities-how-to-define-left-join-for-grouping)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

adapted from MSDN, [how to left join using EF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

```
var query = from u in usergroups
            join p in UsergroupPrices on u.UsergroupID equals p.UsergroupID into gj
            from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { 
                UsergroupID = u.UsergroupID,
                UsergroupName = u.UsergroupName,
                Price = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.Price) 
            };
```

Comment: I like this better than

    where gj.DefaultIfEmpty()

at the end because I can use x in the where or select!

Comment: Can you explain the 'from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()' line?

Comment: @AlexDresko this part takes all the results from the join , and for the ones that have no right hand value , gives you null (default of object being null). hth

Comment: Thanks @Menahem, but it seems like it would be null by default? What happens if you don't do the DefaultIfEmpty thing? Does it not do a left outer join? It seems like a really weird thing to have to do.

Comment: @AlexDresko , it's clunky i agree. i`m guessing this is because the group join operation isn't really an SQL like join , as it returns a hierarchical result rather than a flat table.

Comment: @Menahem u equals p.UsergroupID  is this correct ? I think we need u.columnName

Comment: what if price isn't a string but an int?

Comment: @AlexDresko its a bit late but without DefaultIfEmpty you end up with an inner join instead of a full outer join.

Comment: What if there are more than two tables?

Comment: This changed slightly with efcore; `from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()` becomes `from p in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#left-join

Answer (score 51):

Please make your life easier (don't use join into group):

```
var query = from ug in UserGroups
            from ugp in UserGroupPrices.Where(x => x.UserGroupId == ug.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new 
            { 
                UserGroupID = ug.UserGroupID,
                UserGroupName = ug.UserGroupName,
                Price = ugp != null ? ugp.Price : 0 //this is to handle nulls as even when Price is non-nullable prop it may come as null from SQL (result of Left Outer Join)
            };
```

Comment: Avoiding join into group is a matter of opinion, but it's certainly a valid opinion. `Price = ugp.Price` may fail if `Price` is a non-nullable property and the left join doesn't give any results though.

Comment: Agree with above, but with more than two tables this approach is so much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: We can check if `ugp == NULL` and set a default value for `Price`.

Comment: just perfect :)

Comment: Awesome!  I prefer this solution for readability.  Also, this makes more joins (i.e. from 3 or more table) much easier!  I used it successfully for 2 left joins (i.e. 3 tables).

Comment: What if we want a list from right table ?? not a single value like price.

Answer (score 49):

It might be a bit of an overkill, but I wrote an extension method, so you can do a `LeftJoin` using the `Join` syntax (at least in method call notation):

```
persons.LeftJoin(
    phoneNumbers,
    person => person.Id,
    phoneNumber => phoneNumber.PersonId,
    (person, phoneNumber) => new
        {
            Person = person,
            PhoneNumber = phoneNumber?.Number
        }
);
```

My code does nothing more than adding a `GroupJoin` and a `SelectMany` call to the current expression tree. Nevertheless, it looks pretty complicated because I have to build the expressions myself and modify the expression tree specified by the user in the `resultSelector` parameter to keep the whole tree translatable by LINQ-to-Entities.

```
public static class LeftJoinExtension
{
    public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TOuter> outer,
        IQueryable<TInner> inner,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, TKey>> outerKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TInner, TKey>> innerKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>> resultSelector)
    {
        MethodInfo groupJoin = typeof (Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                 .Single(m => m.ToString() == "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TResult] GroupJoin[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TOuter], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TInner], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TOuter,TKey]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TInner,TKey]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[TOuter,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TInner],TResult]])")
                                                 .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TOuter), typeof (TInner), typeof (TKey), typeof (LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>));
        MethodInfo selectMany = typeof (Queryable).GetMethods()
                                                  .Single(m => m.ToString() == "System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TResult] SelectMany[TSource,TCollection,TResult](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[TSource], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[TSource,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TCollection]]], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`3[TSource,TCollection,TResult]])")
                                                  .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>), typeof (TInner), typeof (TResult));

        var groupJoinResultSelector = (Expression<Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>>>)
                                      ((oneOuter, manyInners) => new LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner> {OneOuter = oneOuter, ManyInners = manyInners});

        MethodCallExpression exprGroupJoin = Expression.Call(groupJoin, outer.Expression, inner.Expression, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, groupJoinResultSelector);

        var selectManyCollectionSelector = (Expression<Func<LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>, IEnumerable<TInner>>>)
                                           (t => t.ManyInners.DefaultIfEmpty());

        ParameterExpression paramUser = resultSelector.Parameters.First();

        ParameterExpression paramNew = Expression.Parameter(typeof (LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>), "t");
        MemberExpression propExpr = Expression.Property(paramNew, "OneOuter");

        LambdaExpression selectManyResultSelector = Expression.Lambda(new Replacer(paramUser, propExpr).Visit(resultSelector.Body), paramNew, resultSelector.Parameters.Skip(1).First());

        MethodCallExpression exprSelectMany = Expression.Call(selectMany, exprGroupJoin, selectManyCollectionSelector, selectManyResultSelector);

        return outer.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(exprSelectMany);
    }

    private class LeftJoinIntermediate<TOuter, TInner>
    {
        public TOuter OneOuter { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TInner> ManyInners { get; set; }
    }

    private class Replacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        private readonly ParameterExpression _oldParam;
        private readonly Expression _replacement;

        public Replacer(ParameterExpression oldParam, Expression replacement)
        {
            _oldParam = oldParam;
            _replacement = replacement;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp == _oldParam)
            {
                return _replacement;
            }

            return base.Visit(exp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this extension fero.

Comment: This is still great.  Thanks!

Comment: Tested this within .NET Framework 4.6.2 and it works as expected (i.e. generates a LEFT OUTER JOIN). I am wondering if it works on .NET Core though. Thanks.

Comment: Why ef doesn't default to left join is mind boggling. Many database engines will do an entire table scan against the other table even if no rows are returned from the main table.

Comment: I confirm this works in EF Core

Answer (score 8):

If you prefer method call notation, you can force a left join using `SelectMany` combined with `DefaultIfEmpty`. At least on Entity Framework 6 hitting SQL Server. For example:

```
using(var ctx = new MyDatabaseContext())
{
    var data = ctx
    .MyTable1
    .SelectMany(a => ctx.MyTable2
      .Where(b => b.Id2 == a.Id1)
      .DefaultIfEmpty()
      .Select(b => new
      {
        a.Id1,
        a.Col1,
        Col2 = b == null ? (int?) null : b.Col2,
      }));
}
```

(Note that `MyTable2.Col2` is a column of type `int`). 
The generated SQL will look like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id1] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent1].[Col1] AS [Col1], 
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Col2] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE  CAST( [Extent2].[Col2] AS int) END AS [Col2]
    FROM  [dbo].[MyTable1] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[MyTable2] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent2].[Id2] = [Extent1].[Id1]
```

Comment: For me this is generating some extremely slow query with "CROSS APPLY" in it.

Comment: Thanks a million, Helped me so much.

Answer (score 3):

For 2 and more left joins (left joining creatorUser and initiatorUser )

```
IQueryable<CreateRequestModel> queryResult = from r in authContext.Requests
                                             join candidateUser in authContext.AuthUsers
                                             on r.CandidateId equals candidateUser.Id
                                             join creatorUser in authContext.AuthUsers
                                             on r.CreatorId equals creatorUser.Id into gj
                                             from x in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                             join initiatorUser in authContext.AuthUsers
                                             on r.InitiatorId equals initiatorUser.Id into init
                                             from x1 in init.DefaultIfEmpty()

                                             where candidateUser.UserName.Equals(candidateUsername)
                                             select new CreateRequestModel
                                             {
                                                 UserName = candidateUser.UserName,
                                                 CreatorId = (x == null ? String.Empty : x.UserName),
                                                 InitiatorId = (x1 == null ? String.Empty : x1.UserName),
                                                 CandidateId = candidateUser.UserName
                                             };
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by calling the DefaultIfEmpty() on the main model. This allowed me to left join on lazy loaded entities, seems more readable to me:

```
        var complaints = db.Complaints.DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Where(x => x.DateStage1Complete == null || x.DateStage2Complete == null)
            .OrderBy(x => x.DateEntered)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                ComplaintID = x.ComplaintID,
                CustomerName = x.Customer.Name,
                CustomerAddress = x.Customer.Address,
                MemberName = x.Member != null ? x.Member.Name: string.Empty,
                AllocationName = x.Allocation != null ? x.Allocation.Name: string.Empty,
                CategoryName = x.Category != null ? x.Category.Ssl_Name : string.Empty,
                Stage1Start = x.Stage1StartDate,
                Stage1Expiry = x.Stage1_ExpiryDate,
                Stage2Start = x.Stage2StartDate,
                Stage2Expiry = x.Stage2_ExpiryDate
            });
```

Comment: Here, you don't need `.DefaultIfEmpty()` at all: it only affects what happens when `db.Complains` is empty. `db.Complains.Where(...).OrderBy(...).Select(x => new { ..., MemberName = x.Member != null ? x.Member.Name : string.Empty, ... })`, without any `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, would already perform a left join (assuming the `Member` property is marked as optional).

Answer (score 1):

If UserGroups has a one to many relationship with UserGroupPrices table, then in EF, once the relationship is defined in code like:

```
//In UserGroups Model
public List<UserGroupPrices> UserGrpPriceList {get;set;}

//In UserGroupPrices model
public UserGroups UserGrps {get;set;}
```

You can pull the left joined result set by simply this:

```
var list = db.UserGroupDbSet.ToList();
```

assuming your DbSet for the left table is UserGroupDbSet, which will include the UserGrpPriceList, which is a list of all associated records from the right table.

Answer (score -1):

That's how to write a LEFT JOIN with lambda syntax:

```cs
var result = _db.TableOne
    .Where(one => one.Id < 10000)
    .GroupJoin(_db.TableTwo,
        one => one.TwoId,
        two => two.Id,
        (one, twos) => new { one, twos })
    .SelectMany(
        item => item.twos.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (g, two) => new { g.one, two });
```

Note: this is not an answer to the question - it's a note for googlers who land here after searching for "ef left join lambda".