# Linq - Inner Join not retrieving all records from left table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have done an inner join, it shows only the matching record with following query :-

```
var data = from t1 in ctx.tblEmp
           join t2 in ctx.tblHelp 
               on t1.Field equals t2.Fld
           where t1.Id == Id && 
                 t2.Id == Id
           select new Settings { Master = t1.Labelname, OrderNo = t2.OrderNo};
```

I want all the records from `tblEmp` & only matching records from `tblHelp`.

How to do this?

Comment: That is a left join and not an inner join then. You can search for that here on SO.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use as

```
 var data = from t1 in ctx.tblEmp
       join t2 in ctx.tblHelp 
           on t1.Field equals t2.Fld into u
           from t2 in u.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where t1.Id == Id && 
             t2.Id == Id

       select new Settings { Master = t1.Labelname, OrderNo = t2.OrderNo};
```

Try this

```
 var data = from t1 in ctx.tblEmp
       join t2 in ctx.tblHelp 
           on t1.Field equals t2.Fld into u
           from t2 in u.DefaultIfEmpty()
       where t1.Id == Id 
       orderby columnname // Added Order By
       select new Settings { Master = t1.Labelname, OrderNo = t2.OrderNo==null ?"":t2.OrderNo};
```

Comment: Still gives me only matching records.

Comment: I get error `The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`

Comment: @Anup Try now check null condition

Comment: Finally Worked...Thanks a lot..@

Comment: Just one last thing...how to `OrderBy` 'OrderNo' in above query

Answer (score 1):

```
    var query = from t1 in ctx.tblEmp
                    join t2 in ctx.tblHelp on t1 equals t2.Fld into tempGroup
                    from subpet in tempGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { t1.Labelname, OrderNo = (subpet == null ? String.Empty : subpet.OrderNo) };
```