# How can I use a custom method in a LINQ-to-SQL select clause?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I would like to do something like what is described in [this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/). However, the article is from 2006, and requires extension methods the author wrote. I'm hoping there's something more built-in at this point.

The intent here is to save a method that contains only operations translatable to T-SQL and use it to assign specific properties in a LINQ-to-SQL select statement. If there's a radically different way to do this then what I've attempted, then that's also a valid answer.

How do I do it?

---

**What I've Tried**

I have a query sort of like this:

```
var theData = (
    from inv in dc.Inventory
    where inv.IsDeleted == false
    join data in cdc.InventoryDatas
    on inv.InvKey equals data.ReInvKey
    where data.ReColKey == colKey
    select new MyClass {
        SerialNumber = inv.SerialNumber,
        Data = InventoryData.DataExpression( data ),
        Name = inv.Name,
    }
);
```

Where `InventoryData.DataExpression` is defined as such:

```
public static Expression<Func<InventoryData, string>> DataExpression = (
    d => d.TextData != null ? d.TextData 
        : d.IntegerData != null ? d.IntegerData.ToString() 
        : d.DecimalData != null ? d.DecimalData.ToString() 
        : d.DateData != null ? d.DateData.ToString() 
        : d.BooleanData != null ? d.BooleanData.ToString()
        : null
);
```

But it's not quite right. How can I make this work?

Comment: Looks like I might be able to use something called LINQKit, which maybe implements the extension methods from that article? Trying it tomorrow.

Comment: Yeah, LINQKit is the way to go for this kind of thing.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448432/pass-expression-parameter-as-argument-to-another-expression/29471092#29471092

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine when select only data from one table, and when I don't combine other expressions in the right side of the assignment statement for the same property:

```
Data = InventoryData.DataExpression.Compile()( data )
```

as do

```
select InventoryData.CompiledDataExpression( data )
```

and

```
select data.GetData()
```

where `CompiledDataExpression` is defined as

```
public static Func<InventoryData, string> CompiledDataExpression 
    = InventoryData.DataExpression.Compile();
```

and `GetData` is defined as

```
public string GetData() {
    // execute the compiled delegete on this InventoryData
    var ret = InventoryData.CompiledDataExpression( this );

    return ret;
}
```

However, the delegate is not actually compiled to T-SQL. Instead, whole objects of the type associated with the table are pulled, and then the delegate is executed upon them locally.

I get an error when I try the full query, which joins on other tables and assigns the delegate to just one of several properties, some of which pull data from the other tables.