# Dynamic Expression from query, Expression call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression-trees

Hy, in my code i have a method that builds a 'where expression'. It looks like this :

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildWhereExpression<T>(Context context, string memberName, string memberValue)
{
    memberValue = memberValue.Trim().RemoveDiacritics().ToLower();

    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

    var propsNames = memberName.Split('.');
    Expression propExpression = param;
    foreach (var propName in propsNames)
    {
        propExpression = Expression.Property(propExpression, propName);
    }

    var methodToLower = typeof(string).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "ToLower" && x.GetParameters().Length == 0);
    var toLowerCall = Expression.Call(propExpression, methodToLower);

    var methodDiacritics = typeof(context).GetMethod("GetStringWithoutDiacritics");
    var funcCall = Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(context), methodDiacritics, toLowerCall);

    var methodContains = typeof(string).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Contains" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
    var containsCall = Expression.Call(funcCall, methodContains, Expression.Constant(memberValue));

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsCall, param);

    return lambda;
}
```

where "GetStringWithouDiacritics" is a scalar function in my database (code first). This produces the folowing, when used with 'Where' :

```
WHERE ([dbo].[GetStringWithoutDiacritics](LOWER([Extent2].[Col1])) LIKE N'%blabla%')
```

This is ok but because that i am using a scalar function in where the performance is terrible. What i want to do is to write the sql code in the function 'inline'. It should produce something like :

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LOWER(Col1) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'ș','s') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'ț','t') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'î', 'i') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'ă', 'a') COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'â', 'a'))
                                     LIKE '%parite%'
```

My question is how cand i modify the method that builds the where expression. I know it is with dynamic expression but i can't figure out how..
, to replace 'Col1' with my actual column, etc..

Comment: dont you simply need .._AI collation? cant you set it in the db?

Answer (score 0):

What db are you using? In MSSQL you can define functions in a way that they can be inlined. I would first explore that way.

If that doesn't work for you, then here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448432/pass-expression-parameter-as-argument-to-another-expression/29471092#29471092) to an answer on how to combine expression trees nicely. You can in this case drop the scalar function, and define your method entirely in C#.