# How to do a left outer join using lambda in EF6

Tags: sql, vb.net, lambda, entity-framework-6

Note: using lambda expressions, not linq

It's probably "end of day brain fry" but I need a little help converting a sql query to EF query using lambda expressions.

```
SELECT *
FROM isf
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ist
ON
    isf.istId = ist.id
and ist.isOpen = 1
where isf.istId = 113
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework left join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join)

Comment: Using lambda, not Linq unless I'm reading you link wrong.

Comment: That's just a syntax detail. What matters is: use GroupJoin (= join - into).

Comment: A better answer it to explain how to use GroupJoin in the context of a lambda expression (like the post indicates) instead of tagging it as a duplicate and then only hinting at what should be done. All you've done is basically lock the question with no answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584820/how-do-you-perform-a-left-outer-join-using-linq-extension-methods