# Join a table with bridge table and get data from main table and if data exists in bridge table then get it as well

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have two tables "Event(EventId,EventName,....,UpdatedBy)", "User(UserId,Username...)" and a bridge table "EventAttendee(EventId,UserId)"

```
from c in context.Events
from u in c.users 
where c.EventId == eventId
select s
```

the above is doing an inner join so if there are no records in EventAttendee table then I am not getting any records.

I want to always get event details from the Event table and if there are any records in EventAttendee table for that event then get the UserId and Username. How to do this in linq to sql using Entity framework since my entity modal does not show bridge table?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join

Comment: @Renat That link doesn't help me because my entity modal doesn't have bridge table. I've updated my description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
from e in context.Events
from u in e.users.DefaultIfEmpty()
where e.EventId == eventId
select ...
```

Not sure what `s` is in the`select`, but it could be something like

```
select new { e.EventName, UserId = (int?)u.UserId, u.UserName }
```

This will give you a list of the event with all of its attendees, or `null` for the user-related data when there are no attendees.

Comment: The `c.users` table isn't empty, so that won't help.

Comment: @NetMage `c.users` is the users collection of an event. The range variable names were a bit confusing. Renamed them.

Comment: @GertArnold  If I select the userid and username into list (Ex:     select new { e.EventName, EventAttendees = new List<EventAttendee>{new EventAttedee {UserId = (int?)u.UserId, UserName = u.UserName}}}), this is actually returning EventAttendees with 1 item with userid null and username empty string. How Can I filter this?

Comment: What do you want to filter?

Comment: @GertArnold I don't want to insert items in to list if userid is null

Comment: But that contradicts "I want to always get event details from the Event table"