# Why does a joined LINQ-to-SQL query generate a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a `Document` table and a `Tenant` table in my database, with a `Document_Tenant` table to relate the two. I'm trying to get a selection of all `Documents`, with related `Tenants`, if any. That should be a left join between `Document` and `Document_Tenant` and an inner join between `Document_Tenant` and `Tenant`, so I followed [Entity framework left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join) to get this code:

```
var combinedQuery = from doc in DocumentProvider.GetDocuments()
                    join dt in CustomTableItemProvider.GetItems<Document_TenantItem>()
                         on doc.ItemID equals dt.Document_ID into ddt
                    from x in ddt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join t in TenantProvider.GetTenants()
                         on x.Tenant_ID equals t.ItemID    // joined tenants
                    select new { doc, t.Tenant_ID };
```

When that query executes, though, I get a NullReferenceException. I'm not sure why.

> Exception type: NullReferenceException
>   Exception message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at lambda_method(Closure , <>f__AnonymousType37`2 , <>f__AnonymousType36`2 )
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__23`3.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: Why not use navigation properties instead?  And why are you getting your related tables from different places instead of all from the same context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a couple of mistakes in my original post. One was that this isn't actually Entity Framework, but an API similar to it. That meant I couldn't use navigation properties as suggested by Steve Py.

Also, and this is the critical one, I oversimplified my code. Where I posted `select new { doc, t }`, my code throwing the exception was `select new { doc, t.Tenant_ID }`. Since this is a left join, the `t` value is sometimes null - which leads to a NullReference exception.

I changed my select to read:

```
select new {
    Doc = doc,
    Tenant_ID = t == null ? null : t.Tenant_ID
};
```

Side note: I'm not sure why we can't use a null coalescing operator in the select, but we can't.

Comment: I had same problem in my unit test method. Tested method worked, but a test not passed and throwed an identical exception as your. Your solution helped. Thanks for sharing with this interesting scenario.