# How to filter the record with Entity Framework and display in datatables

Tags: entity-framework, linq, datatables

I have query (allResponse) that I can display in my view by using datatables:

```
var allResponse = from r in table1
                  select r;

var students = from a in table2
               select a;
```

This is what I tried after suggestions:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetFormResponse()
    {

        //get list of student that match advisor star id only
        //NEXT TASK

         var advisorStarId =  @User.Identity.Name.Substring(User.Identity.Name.IndexOf("\\") + 1);

        //List of all student that belong to advior signed in starId

        var students = from a in _db.ST_ADV_STARID
                .Where(a => a.ADV_STAR_ID == advisorStarId)
                select a;
        //List of all responses

        var allResponse = from r in db.GETTING_TO_KNOW_FORM
                          select r;

        var query = from a in allResponse
                    join b in students on a.STAR_ID equals b.STU_STAR_ID into c
                    from x in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        STAR_ID = a.STAR_ID,
                        PREFERRED_NAME = a.PREFERRED_NAME
                    };

      



        
        return Ok(query);
       
    }
```

**Solved by moving context class to the same file**

But I only would like to display records from table1 that has starId matching starId from table2, and I still would like all field from table1
I have tried too long. I think I would like to some help

Help? Suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Tables are connected?

Comment: Yes, they are connected to database

Comment: So, you're looking to join the two tables where table1.starId = table2.starId ?

Comment: Yes, that' right

Comment: You should post some detail about relationship, but probably you can use left join https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity framework left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
var reselt = from t1 in table1
    join t2 in table2 on t1.STAR_ID equals t2.STU_STAR_ID
    select new
    {
       TABLE1 = t1,
       TABLE2 = t2
    };
```

If you want to access properties from `table1` you can do like `result.TABLE1.{property}` and same for table2 as well.

Comment: Thank you! for your time and help.

Comment: My problem has some to do with Entity Frameworks. I read from this site https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/18143051/what-is-meant-by--the-specified-linq-expression-contains-references-to-queries-that-are-associated-with-different-contexts-    and it helps solved my problem by combined those 2 table contexts in the same file. Thank again!