# Method Returning "int" value from database

Tags: c#, lambda

I have an interface like what u see below and I want it to return me a Property Called "ProductionCostId" which has a type of 'int' from a table in the database

```cs
int Get(Guid productionLineId, string productionCode)
```

In the implementation as you can see I want to get this value from a child entity called "ProductionAssignmetnt"

```cs
public int Get(Guid productionLineId, string productionCode)
{
    return GetAll()
          .Where(x => x.ProductionAssignments
              .Where(x => x.ProductionLine.Id == productionLineId && x.ProductionCode == productionCode)
              .Select(x => x.ProductionCostId);
}
```

But I dont know how to get this int value

Comment: So, when you uncomment that line, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The commented line seems to be returning a list, using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `Where` will return a single int.

Comment: please attach your Model

Comment: I hope that `GetAll()` doesn't really "get all records", but just sets up an IQueryable

Comment: @HansKeﬆing true XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to include the productionassignments table to this query i.e. join it.

In your `GetAll()` method where you return in you can join a table using code first by `_context.ProductionLines.Include(x => x.ProductionAssignments)`, if you're on Database First then read **[this on how to join tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537995/entity-framework-left-join)**

Now since you **haven't posted any model**, this is how you'd select if your `ProductionCostId` is nested inside the assignments

```
GetAll()
      .FirstOrDefault(pLine => pLine.Id == productionLineId)
      ?.ProductionAssignments.FirstOrDefault(assignment =>  assignment.ProductionCode == productionCode)?.ProductionCostId)
```

This query will get the production line with the id, and then select the first `productionCostId` from the assignments where the code matches. This query assumes the Model

```
public class ProductionLine
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<ProductionAssignment> ProductionAssignments {get;set;}
}

public class ProductionAssignment
{
   public int ProductionCode {get;set;}
   public int ProductionCostID {get;set;}
   public ProductionLine ProductionLine {get;set;}
}
```

Beware of null reference exceptions.

Comment: I think he doesn't have ProductionLineId in the main parent table, that's why he was not filtering it directly. Instead, he applied filters on child collections.

Comment: I think he did because in his PrductionAssignments he has a fields `ProductionLine` for which he matches the Id

Comment: thank you guys, your comments were really helpful, the problem fixed